# Who is the most ancient person with the biggest lines of descendants that have been fully attestted?

Tags: genealogy

I was wanting to find the biggest and deepest family tree, but once it's been made, the answer changes constantly over time, so I'm resorting to this.

I'm looking for the person / people who was born the furthest back in time, with as many confirmed descendants as possible, hopefully with at least one of the known descendants being currently alive?

Like if we had a family tree from [Giocangga](https://www.cell.com/ajhg/fulltext/S0002-9297(07)63394-1) to one of his modern-day descendants.

Comment: Muhammad (PBUH) is going to be tough to beat

Comment: @SPavel - If you go back far enough on Ancestry.com, and you have ancestors of European extration, you're quite likely to find Thor (yes the Norse God). And then of course Odin.

Comment: Not sure if every blank is filled, but [Confucius](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/09/20/arts/international/for-confucius-and-his-descendants-a-cultural-comeback.html) might be a decent candidate. I hesitate to post this as an answer because 1) more searching is required for corroboration, and 2) it would look really dumb if someone found a much older one, which is entirely possible.

Comment: FWIW, I believe the Thor thing is because certain Norse kings officially traced their lineage to Thor. So even though the idea is ridiculous, this is in fact the historically documented ancestry of those men, and those are the kinds of records sites like Ancestry use for their database. Likewise there may be many people in Egypt who can trace their lineage back to Ra, but I haven't looked into that.

Answer (score 5):

Short Answer:

The asker doesn't understand the complexities of the question.

Long Answer:

The question actually asks for three different answers:

One) The person who lived the greatest number of years ago with reliably traced descendants to the present time.

Two) The person who lived the greatest number of generations ago with reliably traced descendants to the present time.

Number one and number two are not the same question.  Even over many generations in a lineage, the average length of generations varies between different lineages.  There is no proven lineage long enough to force the average generation in that lineage to be the same length as the statistical average length between the birth of a parent and the birth of their child.

So so it is possible for one lineage to cover more years but fewer and longer generations, while another lineage covers fewer years but more and shorter generations.

[Here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/55176/what-is-the-longest-name-chain/55180#55180) is a link to a question about the longest name chain with the same name repeated in every generation.

My answer mentions the lords, counts, and princes of Reuss, who have named every male in the family Heinrich or Henry ever since the reign of Emperor Henry VI. You might be surprised to know that there have only been 22 generations from a Prince Heinrich born in 2017  to Heinrich IV, Vogt of Weida and Gera, who died in1249 and was probably born before 1217 and thus more than 800 years before his descendant in 22 generations.  So that makes an average of at least 36.3636 years per generation gap in 22 generation gaps.

With 7 generation gaps between 2017 and 1753, the average generation gap is 37.714 years.  With 10 generation gaps between 2017 and 1639, that makes the average generation gap 37.38 years.

So that is a lineage which has had a very long average generation gap for 800 years.

Here is a link to the family tree of the Japanese monarchs in Wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_tree_of_Japanese_monarchs

The earliest generations are mythical, followed by legendary and semi historical generations.  After more than 1,100 years, the first monarch considered fully historical was Kinmei, reportedly born in 509 and reigning from 539 to 571.  AD.

And if I remember correctly, Some time ago I counted that Yoshihito, the Taisho monarch (1879-1926), the great grandfather of the present Tenno, was born 50 generation gaps after Kinmei.   And if you take 10 generation gap lineage segments from the longer 50 generation gap lineage, and calculate the average generation gap, you will find that the average in each segment you choose will be different to a greater or lesser degree than in the other segments and different than in the longer 50 generation average.

And you will find that in each segment and in the 50 generation gap lineage, the average generation gap between births will be somewhat different from the average generation gap between deaths.

And if after taking the average over 50 generation gaps from the Kinmei monarch to the Taisho monarch, you go down a generation and take the average over 50 generation gaps from Kinmeni's son to Taisho's son Hirohito, the Showa Monarch, you should find the birth and death averages ls slightly different.

So I say that, given the relatively short age of the longest fully authenticated lineages, no proven lineage has enough generations to force and ensure that the average generation gap in that lineage equals the statistical average generation gap between parent and child.

So I consider it quite probable that the longest proven lineage in number of years is different from the longest proven lineage in number of generation gaps covered.

And then comes the questions of which lineages are considered proven, and which are considered probable but not proved, and which are considered possible but uncertain, and which are considered certainly fictional, imaginary, and untrue.  And different persons, even different experts, will have different standards for judging the boundaries between those four categories and putting various lineages into those categories.

Three)  Which lineage from far in the past has the greatest number of persons alive today proven to be descended from the earliest ancestor in that lineage.

And that has the problem that the farther back in the past, the fewer the genealogical relationships which were recorded, and the few records that were made survive to the present time.

And it is easy to find genealogical records for the present day head of a dynasty or family and trace his ancestry generation by generation back to their report ancestor.  But they will have many second, third, fourth, fifth, and so on to tenth, and son on to twentieth, etc. cousins which share that ancestry to the remote ancestor who are less well known and whose ancestry might be a lot harder to did up.

And of course there is the problem of judging whether each and every one of tens, hundreds, thousands, tens of thousands, hundreds of thousands, maybe millions, of alleged lineages back to a remote ancestor is accurate.    Even someone certain of his standards of proof will find the process of judging all those lineages and counting the currently living persons in them to be very time consuming.

Conclusion:

I hope that I have explained some of the complexities of the questions you have asked.  And I hope that you and every who answers is aware of how tentative the answers must be.

I may have more to add later.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I *was* wanting to know what the cutting edge of geneaological knowledge is, and this basically answers that, along with giving a guide on what, if any questions are a good idea to ask! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

It is alleged that Kung Yu-jen, born in 2006, whom is the son of [Kung Tsui-chang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kung_Tsui-chang) has the longest ancestral lineage in the world, and is a direct descendant of [Tang of Shang](https://blog.myheritage.com/2012/08/confucius-ancient-family-tree/) 1675–1646 BC, via [Confuscius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confucius#Descendants).

The links I have provided above take you directly to the claims.