What is the highest generational suffix ever used in the United States?
I am hoping to learn more about suffix use in the United States. I am the Ninth (IX), my father was the Eighth (VIII), and so on. I was wondering if anyone knew for sure if there was a higher number out there. The IX on my name is generational and continuous. Have there ever been any other people in the United States that have/had a Tenth, or above, as their suffix?

Just out of curiosity, have you kept the pattern for your son(or are you considering to do so)?

And from the same curiosity, but to a broader public: what are the legal details of such a naming scheme in the USA? It is part of the legal name? Is there any restriction (e.g. the parent must show that there was a John Smith III if he wants to register his son as John Smith IV). Please feel free to move to chat if this is a little bit off topic.

And finally, I would like to point out that there is a [genealogy.se] site. Maybe they can also help. Before posting there, please check their FAQs and help center to see which kind of questions they are willing to accept.

I was told those suffixes were supposed to all rotate upward one when one of the previous holders died. So that would imply your 6xgreat grandfather is still alive.

@T.E.D. I don‘t understand your last comment. Rotate upwards suggests that If there are George I, George II and George III George II becomes George III and George III gets promoted to. George IV after George I died.

I just learned that in 19th century Grand Duchy of Hesse a numeral (Beizeichen) was used to distinguish persons of the same community and of the same name in official documents. There is at least one prominent person that matches your number: the State Representative from Lampertheim Adam Seelinger IX..

@ccprog That hint led me to Adam Seelinger XIV. That's not US though.

@jmk   The use of Roman numerals after names In the USA is different from the use by royalty.  In royalty each new monarch of a country with a specific name gets a number one higher than the previous monarch of that country with that name, regardless of their relationship and regardless of whether previous kings with that name are alive or dead.  But I think that in the USA, numbers only pertain to living members of a family..  So when John Smith I dies his son John Smith II becomes John Smith I and grandson John Smith III becomes John Smith II.    Continued

@j,mk  Continued.  And the numbering system only applies in the line from father to son to grandson, etc., and doesn't apply to uncles, nephews cousins, etc.  But I have heard that the MacArthur family has a different numbering system.  And the family of the Princes of Reuss all the males have been named Henry since the reign of Emperor Henry VI.  And nowdays they all have Roman numbers.  different numbering rules have been used over time, including starting over with a new century, so it would be possible for a Henry I to be the son of a Henry XV or something.  Continued..

@jmk   continued  See https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/55176/what-is-the-longest-name-chain/55180#55180  So the numbering process in your family is rather unusual, but I guess there is nothing wrong with using an unusual system.

@MAGolding I'm sure there's no law demanding that, only custom? Like my family has a custom of giving each son the father's first name as his middle name (and equivalent for daughters and mothers) but there is no law requiring that.

I'm not confident that's correct. For example, Robert Mueller III didn't get downgraded even though both his father (Robert Mueller Jr) and his grandfather are dead. Similarly, RFK Jr is still "Jr" despite the death of his father.

And then there are even stranger cases, such as George Foreman, who named his five sons: George Jr., George III, George IV, George V, and George VI.

Andre 3000..............
